# Consulta em Relacionamento many-to-many com LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

Criei um banco de dados que possui duas tabelas chamadas **Professores** e **Cursos**. Um professor pode dar aula em muitos cursos e um curso pode ter muitos professores.
Criei a tabela **CursosProfessores** para relacionar ambas.
Ao usar o assistente do Entity Framework para fazer o mapeamento, ele não gerou a classe de entidade da tabela CursosProfessores. Ao invés disso, ambas as classes possuem HashSets que representam suas listas de Professores e Cursos.
O problema é que, na aplicação, quando vou tentar inscrever um Professor em um Curso ou inscrever um Curso para um Professor, pode ser que o Professor já esteja relacionado ao Curso e, nesse caso, é lançada uma excessão.
A questão é: como posso recuperar todos os Professores de um Curso ou vice-versa usando a LINQ to Entities?
Se conseguir recuperá-los, poderei tratar o problema de inscrições ambíguas.
Grato desde já.

Answer (score 0):

Faça a pesquisa e traga um `Curso` de código 1, já na relação virá todos os `Professores` relacionados:

```
Cursos curso = db.Cursos.Find(1);

// contem a lista de professores do curso 1
ICollection<Professores> profLista = curso.Professores.ToList();
```

também pode fazer o contrário `Professores` de código 1 traz os `Cursos` relacionados:

```
Professores prof = db.Professores.Find(1);

// contem a lista de cursos do professor 1
ICollection<Cursos> curList = prof.Cursos.ToList();
```

***Referencias:***

- [Entity Framework 6 - Modelando um relacionamento muitos-para-muitos](http://www.macoratti.net/14/05/ef6_mmr1.htm)
- [Configure Many-to-Many relationship](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)
- [How to create a many-to-many mapping in Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19342908/how-to-create-a-many-to-many-mapping-in-entity-framework)
- [Avoid many-to-many mappings in ORMs](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/03/12/avoid-many-to-many-mappings-in-orms/)
- [MVC 5, Entity Framework 6 and Many to Many Relationship : a step by step View Model approach](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/702890/MVC-Entity-Framework-and-Many-to-Many-Relation)

Comment: Não deu certo...A lista de cursos está vindo vazia, mesmo com um professor que está inscrito em 2 cursos.

Comment: @RonyeLago coloque seu código na pergunta por favor, todo o código que está utilizando? *é esse o código usual*

Comment: @RonyeLago verifique se o `Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` coloque `true` para o carregamento preguiçoso.